# Facebook share in Hebrew messed up

Tags: facebook, wordpress, seo, addthis

I have a WordPress website in Hebrew. Using Yoast for SEO and AddThis for sharing. 
Recently a lot of problems with Facebook sharing: Some posts share in "Gibbrish" - no image, no title and messed up description, some posts don't.

Tried to disable Yoast OG parameters, and tried to manually add descriptions for pages' social sections.  I also check UTF settings and couple of Facebook plugins with no results.

Comment: Care to share the site address? Yoast adds FB data no problem normally.

Comment: @felix91 Have you install this version of WordPress http://he.wordpress.org/

Comment: @felix91 addthis also has language settings http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381240-languages?addthis_language=he#api

Comment: The only weird thing that I could find about your website is that it forbids `head` requests:   `$ curl --head http://www.agamy.co.il/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I get 

HTTP/1.0 200 OK => 
Date => Fri, 04 Jul 2014 23:14:27 GMT
Server => LiteSpeed
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Connection => close
ETag => "467a-53b7351e-0"
Last-Modified => Fri, 04 Jul 2014 23:13:34 GMT
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length => 18042
Pragma => public
Cache-Control => public, max-age=3547
X-Powered-By => W3 Total Cache/0.9.4
Expires => Sat, 05 Jul 2014 00:13:34 GMT

Comment: I don't understand what it means and what to do with it =\

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very old question, but you can debug that kind of problems with [Facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).

[Here you can see](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.agamy.co.il%2F) your page OG Meta tags are messed up, I don't know why you're serving different content for Facebook (maybe all the bots?) but the culprit is the way your headlings.

```
[custom_headline type=" center level="h2" looks_like="h3" accent="true" professionals type="whole" class="center-text" no_margin="true" etc...
```

Looks some kind of plugin or maybe part of your theme to show headlines etc. But it's bugged. It has nothing to do with Hebrew or characters encoding.

Comment: Yes thank you, I found a way to deal with it. The debugger is my friend now... Facebook messing up everytihng